# I am getting 404 not found error while the route exisits

Tags: laravel, routes, http-status-code-404

I am using **Laravel** to build my todo app.

In the **web.php** routes file i have added this route:

```
Route::put('/tasks/changecat', 'TaskController@changeCat');
```

and i am calling this route from a form in a **.blade.php** file like so:

```
<form action="tasks/changecat" id="change-cat-form" class="d-none" method="POST">
    @method('PUT')
    @csrf
    <input type="text" name="task" id="task-input">
    <input type="text" name="category" id="category-input">
</form>
```

But when i try to submit the form on the browser i get 404 not found

[image: what the browser shows]

I tried to use postman and i have included the csrf token in the headings, i get a **200 ok** but i get redirected to the login page.

what do you think it's causing the problem?

Comment: Can you link us the repository on GitHub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this when i changed the method to **PATCH**.

```
Route::patch('/tasks/changecat', 'TaskController@changeCat');
```

It turns out that i should use PATCH because i needed to change a part of the resource and not all of it.

Using PATCH will change the 'updated_at' column value automatically too.